# users adding images

Tags: users, media

I am wondering what the best option would be for adding images to Drupal 7.

I am running a new social media site for cats and their catlover humans at http://aimable.ghookermls.info/. My authenticated users want to add images, including animated gifs, easily. I don't want the images to be too large, which would either mess up the display, take too long to load, take up too much disk space, or some combination thereof. I also don't want the images to interfere with other aspects of the site.

Here's what I have tried, and why it is not working optimally:

**Image with Article.** Only one image allowed per article, and Statuses (fbsmp) do not allow that to work properly.

**Statuses / Facebook-style micropublisher.** Images are compressed rather than resized; resizing cuts off the right edge; and the fbsmp module is interfering with images in articles.

**IMCE.** Works with CKEditor for most users; for others, they cannot upload. When I browse their files as administrator, I get the following error:

- Directory u(%n) is not accessible.
- Unable to get a working directory for the file browser!
- Notice: Undefined index: perm in include()
  (line 14 of /home/.../public_html/.../sites/all/modules/imce/tpl/imce-file-list.tpl.php).

Also, some images are too wide and spill over into the right sidebar.

**Drupal Wall.** I tested it, giving only administrators permission to create posts. Authenticated users could post and comment on nodes, and anonymous users could view posts. Also, «Image Style: _none» appeared below the image when viewing the node with the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CKeditor, you could try the [Auto Resize](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Image-Resize) plugin.

> This Plugin provides a small image processor. You can limit the size of images
>   directly on the client without upload images on your server. Big images will be
>   resized automatically on paste.

This would prevent you from ever having the larger images uploaded to the server in the first place by doing the resize automatically in the editor before the node is saved.

Answer (score 0):

you could try one of the following:

- create a new content type, add an image field - you can choose how many images the user is permitted to uploaded in the field settings
- use the modules [Multiupload FileField Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget) with [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) in any Content type to allow multiple uploads at once

In either case, you can set file size limits, and use an image style to style it further on Manage Display